# Fullcalendar isn't loading my json to show events

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I've been messing around with the fullcalendar java script and I can't seem to get the calendar to load any of the data my mysql database.

My db-connect.php file returns the first entry in the table when I test it, but still isn't populated onto the calendar.

```
<?php
// List of events
$events = array();

// connection to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","database");

//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//fetches and sends data in string
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id");
$events = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($events);
?>
```

I also have a get_events.php that I tried setting up to only pull the date range. It doesn't pull any info when I test it but that should be because I'm testing it without a date range.

```
<?php
// List of events
$events = array();
$start = $_GET["start"];
$end = $_GET["end"];

// connection to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","agaraapp_events","!QAZ@WSX3edc4rfv","agaraapp_events");

//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//fetches and sends data in string
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE start >= '$start' AND end <= '$end'");
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $e = array();
   $e['id'] = $fetch['id'];
   $e['title'] = $fetch['title'];
   $e['start'] = $fetch['start'];
   $e['end'] = $fetch['end'];
   array_push($events, $e);
}
echo json_encode($events);
?>
```

Then here is my calendar code.

```
   <head>    
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="CalendarJava/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="CalendarJava/main.js"></script>
        <script>
          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
              schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
              initialView: 'dayGridMonth',  
                events: {
            url: 'get_events.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data : {
            },
            success : function(response){
              }
       }  
             });
            calendar.render();
          });    
        </script>    
      </head>
```

I've changed the url to both get_events.php and db-connect.php but everytime I load it up it shows a blank calendar. I'm guessing I need an Ajax code but I'm not very schooled up on those. If that's what I'm missing then I'll try and study up on it and add it in.

Any help with what is going wrong would be helpful. I've read a bunch of of "related" issues on this but none of those problems seem to be correcting my problem.

**EDIT1**

db-connect.php returns the following results, which appears to be the correct format

```
{"id":"1","title":"Test","start":"2021-02-06 10:38:24","end":"2021-02-06 12:38:24"}
```

There are no errors on the server side either

Comment: `I'm guessing I need an Ajax code`...no, fullCalendar handles making the AJAX request for you automatically (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed). However, you do need to do some basic debugging and check that a) the request succeeds (i.e. no errors in the browser console, no non-200 response code in the Network tool, no errors recorded in the PHP error log (or shown in the response to the AJAX), and b) that the JSON data returned 1) contains at least one item, and 2) the data is in the format required by fullCalendar. If you're unsure about any of that, provide more detail.

Comment: I updated the original content under "EDIT1" to show most of the questions you asked. I'm going to go over the events-json-feed link again to see if i missed something.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That's the correct format for a single event, but what you return to fullCalendar needs to be an array (even if it only has one item within it). Adjust your PHP code so that it declares an empty array, then loops through all the rows from the query result, and puts each row into the array. Then, encode that array as JSON and echo it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following, which first returns the JSON response as array and second the correct response header is set.

```
<?php
  // List of events
  $events = array();

  // connection to the database
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","database");

  //check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit;
  }

  //fetches and sends data in string
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id");
  while ($event = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $events[] = $event;
  };

  // response should be associated with the correct header setting
  header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

  // now we can JSON the response
  echo json_encode($events);

  // in case we have some more code afterwards in some if statements 
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: This helped with the editing of the PHP file, very useful information given. I tested it and it is now returning all my events as an array. Just need to get the event calendar to show the results now. Will post an update once I get that to work.

Comment: Managed to get the array to populate correctly on my calendar, this PHP code fixed 99% of my issue.